# Creating setup project with single output file (Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, installation, visual-studio-project

I'm using visual studio 2005 Setup project to create an installer for my application.
The outputs of the setup projects are:
- Setup.exe (a bootstrapper which makes installed .Net framework if it doesn't exist)
- .Net framework folder (for installation by the .exe above)
- .msi installation for my project (called by the setup.exe)

My question is:

Is there any way I can have a single .exe (or msi) installation which makes the entire
installation (and encapsulates all the functionallity menationed above) ?

Answer (score 4):

It seams that the Visual Studio installer doen't let you create a single installation file.

I finally decided to use Win-Zip self extractor to create a single installation file which extract all of the above files and run the setup.exe

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using visual studio standard setup and then combining the exe and msi with [Make SFX](http://74.cz/en/makesfx/) since it supports command line (for automatic builds) and is free.

Answer (score -1):

[SFX Compiler](http://www.uticasoft.com/) is a free program that will create self extracting .exe files for you.

Comment: I think the domain's expired. Try http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/SFX-Compiler.shtml